# PHP - SOAP response to JSON

Tags: php, json, soap

I am trying to parse SOAP response to JSON. So far I have this code:

```
$data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
    $data .= '<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">';
    $data .= '<soap12:Body>';
    $data .= '<GetCommunities xmlns="url">';
    $data .= '<APIUsername>string</APIUsername>';
    $data .= '<APIPassword>string</APIPassword>';
    $data .= '</GetCommunities>';
    $data .= '</soap12:Body>';
    $data .= '</soap12:Envelope>';

    $soap_do = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            "url" );
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $data);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($data) ));

    $result = curl_exec($soap_do);
echo $result;
```

This code is working and I am getting following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetCommunitiesResponse xmlns="url">
            <GetCommunitiesResult>
                <Communities>
                    <CommunityID>1</CommunityID>
                    <CommunityName> Not Specified</CommunityName>
                </Communities>
                <Communities>
                    <CommunityID>276</CommunityID>
                    <CommunityName>Bella Toscana</CommunityName>
                </Communities>
                <Communities>
                    <CommunityID>31</CommunityID>
                    <CommunityName>Crescent Lakes</CommunityName>
                </Communities>
                <Communities>
                    <CommunityID>62</CommunityID>
                    <CommunityName>Hillcrest Estate</CommunityName>
                </Communities>
                <Communities>
                    <CommunityID>750</CommunityID>
                    <CommunityName>Sunny Beach</CommunityName>
                </Communities>
                <Communities>
                    <CommunityID>124</CommunityID>
                    <CommunityName>Terra Verde Resort</CommunityName>
                </Communities>
                <Communities>
                    <CommunityID>744</CommunityID>
                    <CommunityName>The Dales at West Haven</CommunityName>
                </Communities>
                <Communities>
                    <CommunityID>158</CommunityID>
                    <CommunityName>Westridge</CommunityName>
                </Communities>
            </GetCommunitiesResult>
        </GetCommunitiesResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need to create JSON response from the data which can be found between **GetCommunitiesResult** tags. How can I do this?

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Traverse the XML and create a corresponding object while doing so. Serialize that object using `json_encode()` and you're done.

Comment: How can I traverse the XML :D?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edited and [tested](http://www.tecbrat.com/stackoverflow_samples/soap_to_json.php)

```
// a bit of a hack, but let's see...
list($trash,$result)=explode('<soap:Body>',$result);
list($result,$trash)=explode('</soap:Body>',$result);
unset($trash);
$result=str_replace('xmlns="url"','',$result);

$simple_result=simplexml_load_string($result);
$json_result=json_encode($simple_result);

//var_export($simple_result);
echo $json_result;
```

Output:

> {"GetCommunitiesResult":{"Communities":[{"CommunityID":"1","CommunityName":"
>   Not Specified"},{"CommunityID":"276","CommunityName":"Bella
>   Toscana"},{"CommunityID":"31","CommunityName":"Crescent
>   Lakes"},{"CommunityID":"62","CommunityName":"Hillcrest
>   Estate"},{"CommunityID":"750","CommunityName":"Sunny
>   Beach"},{"CommunityID":"124","CommunityName":"Terra Verde
>   Resort"},{"CommunityID":"744","CommunityName":"The Dales at West
>   Haven"},{"CommunityID":"158","CommunityName":"Westridge"}]}}

Comment: This is giving me an empty object.

Comment: Typo `$simple_result` vs `$simlpe_result`.

Comment: I was just reviewing my own idea and trying to decide if this is a good answer. Let me test it and see what I come up with...

Comment: Okay, it doesn't work yet. Let me look into it. `Warning: simplexml_load_string(): namespace warning : xmlns: URI url is not absolute in ...`

Comment: Okay, since you specifically want just the GetCommunitiesResult node, I stripped it out of the envelope. Since I got a namespace error and the namespace wasn't doing anything for me, I removed that as well.

Comment: Also, you don't have to use `$simple_result` and `$json_result`. I just did that for clarity in the example. You might choose to just keep modifying the `$result` variable.

Comment: It is working :). Thanks for the help and extra explanation :)